# What is the difference of single "=" vs "==" operator in where clause in Linq - C#

Tags: c#, linq

With a sample code I have below, Im trying to understand what is the exact difference between "=" operator vs "==" in the where clause?

I have list of items with a property of IsActive.
When I do this:

`GetAllItemsFromCache` -- just returns `List<Item>` 2 of them are `IsActive` `False`, 8 of them are `True`

```
// this return 10 items whereas 2 of them were `IsActive` property was set to `false`in the initial list, but now IsActive seems true for all the items
bool someFlag = true;
var result = GetAllItemsFromCache().Where(i => i.IsActive = someFlag).ToList();
```

```
// this return nothing - In the list 2 of them were `IsActive` property was set to `false` 
bool someFlag = false;
var result = GetAllItemsFromCache().Where(i => i.IsActive = someFlag).ToList();
```

```
// using regular == operator just returns as expected based on the flag. No question here
bool someFlag = false;
var result = GetAllItemsFromCache().Where(i => i.IsActive == someFlag).ToList();
```

Can someone explain? (or if you share a link so I can read details)

Comment: `=` is assignment. Do not use it if you do not want to assign a new value. `==` is comparison, use it when you want to check for equality.

Comment: `i.IsActive = someFlag` means you are assigning `someFlag` to `IsActive` and then return the value of `IsActive`.

Comment: But it returns nothing when the someFlag is false tho. Wouldnt it return all the items and assign  their IsActive to false in that case?

Comment: @Sean - Does that work exact same way with .ForEach(x=>x.IsActive = someFlag) ? So basically var result = GetAllItemsFromCache().ForEach(x=>x.IsActive = someFlag).Where(i => someFlag == true).ToList();  same with what I have in post?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C#, the assignement expression using the `=` operator returns the assigned value, so since `someFlag` is a boolean, the value returned by `i.IsActive = someFlag` is the value of `someFlag`

Here is the language specification :

> The result of a simple assignment expression is the value assigned to
> the left operand. The result has the same type as the left operand and
> is always classified as a value.

More information here :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#assignment-operators

Answer (score 0):

In C# the '=' is used when a variable is initalized.

```
int a = 5;
int b = 6;
```

Here 'a' equals with 5 and 'b' equals with 6.

The '==' is used when you want to decide something.

```
int a = 5;
int b = 6;
bool c = true;
if (a == b){
    c = true
}
else{
    c = false
}
```

This piece of code gives true out when 'a' and 'b' equals.